# xlst transform doens't close tags

Tags: java, html, xslt, pdf, itext

I'm transforming an xml file into a html file with a xslt transformation:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xsl"));
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

Source text = new StreamSource(new File("test.xml"));
transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.html")));
```

When I do this, I get a html file, that can be opened with a browser, but when I try to transform that html to a pdf file with iText, I get an exception, because some tags aren't closed properly. Example: `<br>` (instead of `<br/>`).

Can I somehow instruct the transformer to always close tags?

Comment: Show us the `transform.xsl` file.

Answer (score 3):

The most probable reason is that you are using the HTML output method in your style sheet:

`<xsl:output method="html">`

You should use

`<xsl:output method="xml">`

if you require the XML (XHTML) serialization.

More information can be found in the official specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output

Comment: Note also, it might be that you're selecting method="html" implicitly rather than explicitly: it's the default if the outermost element of your result tree is "html".